# django show field from related model in form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I just don't get it. I have been reading but I am not even close to find the answer. It is most likely extremely easy. I have two models Person (Name and zipcode) and Zip (Zipcode and city).

When registering a new person the field name and zipcode should be entered. When zipcode is entered the related correct city from the Zipmodel should be shown

models.py

```
    class Zip(models.Model):
        zipcode = models.IntegerField()
        city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.zipcode)
    
    class Person(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        zipcode =  models.ForeignKey('Zip',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)  
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms 
    from .models import Zip, Person
    
    class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Person
            fields = ('name', 'zipcode',)
            
    class ZipForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Zip
            fields = ('zipcode', 'city',)
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
    from .forms import PersonForm, ZipForm
    from .models import Zip, Person
    
    def index(request):
        return render(request, 'theapp/index.html' )
    
    def person_new(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = PersonForm(request.POST)
    
    
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
    
                post.save()
                return redirect('person_detail', pk=post.pk)
            
        else:
            form = PersonForm()
        return render(request, 'theapp/person.html', {'form': form})
    
    def zip_new(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ZipForm(request.POST)
            
    
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.save()
                return redirect('zip_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            form = ZipForm()
        return render(request, 'theapp/zip.html', {'form': form})
    
    
    
    def person_detail(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'theapp/person_detail.html', {'post': post})
    
    def zip_detail(request, pk):
        post = get_object_or_404(Zip, pk=pk)
        return render(request, 'theapp/zip_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

person.html

```
    {% block body %}
        <section>
            <h2>new person</h2>
               </section>
    
               
               <form method="POST" class="person-form">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-secondary">Save person</button>
            </form>
    
    
    {% endblock %}
```

This is what I want it to look like. When zipcode is entered. New York is shown.

[image: w]

I would so much appreciate any help or pointing me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can do this in your `forms.py`:

```py
    from django import forms
    from .models import Zip

    class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
        zipcode = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Zip.objects.all(),
                                         empty_label="select zip code",
                                         to_field_name="name")
```

Then on your template you must see the city displayed instead of your zip codes you can see the name of the city is displayed.

Then is the easiest and cleanest way around this. Other methods will be really sophisticated..

Comment: I might be misunderstanding but this is the other way around. I'm trying to show related city (from model Zip) when entering zipcode (in model Person).

Comment: I think you mean a functionality like an autocomplete field? if so, there are a few ways you can achieve this. one way is to use ajax. you create a view that accepts a zip code and then searches it in the db and returns the corresponding name, and on the front-end side after receiving the response you modify your code the show the sent back data. you can create a disabled text field to just show the name of the city. i hope i've gotten it right.

Comment: Well... sort of. I am new to django. And I am finding it so hard to figure this out. I mean this should be used all the time. Imagine you enter the customer number in a field on the order and adress is automaticly shown. You enter a partnumber and name, price etc is filled out. 

This is sort of one of the most basic things using a database type relational where the tables do not contain the same data. So when entering the zipcode in a persons adress table you should be able to show the city from another table with zipcodes and cities matching the zipcode.

Comment: actually it is not used all the time; at least not using Django. what you are trying to achieve has to do with the front-end side. your job however as the back-end developer is to write functions, views, apis, etc. to process and store data. on the other side, front-end developer's job is to find a way to structure and display the returned data by you.

Comment: Well. I guess that makes sense. But for this little project I need to find a sollution using whatever I need to make it. Any front-end developer suggestions then? :) Thank you ;)

Comment: sure. i'll just edit my earlier answer so you an use it.

Comment: Well. I played a little bit with it. But nothing. It is it not the zipcode I want. I want to enter the zipcode in the personform and then show the corresponding, related city from the zip model there. The zipcodefield in person has foreingkey model zipcode. Thanks again for your patience.